# How to create Repository Classes in MVC3 (Entity Framework)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I created a project using **MVC3 - Entity Framework**. I like to use Repository Pattern together with it. I am new to repository pattern. Do I need to create **ONE EACH Repository for each Model Class** (classes which represent each table in the database) and within each repository do I have to write **all the functions which will Insert, Update, Delete and Fetch record**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't. You can implement a GenericRepository for all your classes and then override it if you need to add functions. First i am gonna show you the unit of work. Through this class you can access all the repositories. I have added to this example one generic and one overrided:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    FBDbContext context = new FBDbContext();

    public FBDbContext Context { get { return context;  } }

    private BlockRepository BlockRepository;        
    private GenericRepository<Category> CategoryRepository;                     

    #region RepositoryClasses
    public IBlockRepository blockRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.BlockRepository == null)
                this.BlockRepository = new BlockRepository(context);
            return BlockRepository;
        }
    }        
    public IGenericRepository<Category> categoryRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.CategoryRepository == null)
                this.CategoryRepository = new GenericRepository<Category>(context);
            return CategoryRepository;
        }
    }        
#endregion

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Then you have the generic repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    internal FBDbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(FBDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity Create()
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return dbSet;
    }
    //And all the functions you want in all your model classes...
}
```

and an example when you want to override the generic repository:

```
public class BlockRepository : GenericRepository<Block>
{
    public BlockRepository(FBDbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IEnumerable<Block> GetByCategory(Category category)
    {
        return context.Blocks.Where(r => r.CategoryId == category.Id);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create common repository which will have common methods, all other repositories will be it's children:

```
public class MyModelRepository : GenericRepository<MyModel>
{
   // extend
}

var MyModelRepository = new MyModelRepository();
```

See [this](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle), or google for "Generic Repository" :). If your don't need extended functionality for some model repository, then you can even not create repository class, instead do something like this:

```
var MyModelRepository = new GenericRepository<MyModel>();
```

Comment: I have tables like - Student, Department, Course, Instructor etc and also
 
Model Classes (Student.cs, Department.cs etc ) for each of them inside my Model Folder.
 
1. Do I need to create classes like - IStuderntRepositor, StudentRepository,
 
IDepartmentRepository, DepartmentRepository,
 
ICourseRepository, CourseRepository,
 
IInstructorRepository, IInstructorRepository etc.
 
2. What about the functions which insert,delete,select and update data from each table?
Do I have to write those functions in each of those repositories.
For example function InserStudent, GetStudentAndDepartment()?

Comment: @user2215116 no, I said, crud operations and basic functions will be in generic repository and you don't have to write them each time

Comment: Thanks very much karaxuna, I had a look at the link in your post. I think the author is not using UnitOfWork. What is the role of UnitOfWork? Where should I use it?

Comment: @user2215116 take a look at this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Hi, How to call stored procedure using repository classes? I have some functions in my context class - public partial class MyEntities  DbContext. Those fuctions were created for calling StoredProcedures. How do I access those functions from my repository class?

Comment: @user2215116 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework

Answer (score 0):

Have an interface that represents the common operations between each repository. I.e. Insert, Update, Delete and Fetch:

```
 public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        void Insert(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Fetch(T entity);
    }

 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> 
   /// your implementation
 }
```

Then in each model you could define the repository to suit the context, for instance:

```
  var repository1 = new Repository<ModelType>(dataContext);
  repository1.Insert(obj);

  var repository2 = new Repository<DifferentModelType>(dataContext);
  repository2.Fetch(objects);
```

http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/