# MVC DBContext, how to connect to a table?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

im just creating my first MVC applicaiton and am having trouble connecting to my database located on my sql server.

i have added the connection string to the web config as normal, created a model with all the fields in.

i created a model and created a new DBContext as there wasnt one listed. this created the below file

im not sure how it connects to the right table in my SQLDB, how do i do this?
also how do i make it run stored procedures?

Thanks

```
public EquipmentDBContext()
            : base("name=ITAPPConnectionString")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
```

Comment: For store procedure: [How to call Stored Procedures with EntityFramework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public EquipmentDBContext()
            : base("name=ITAPPConnectionString")//this name should be the name of database
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
```

here you say you have a 
Datamodoel called Equipment. Your context also defines a single property, Equipments, which is of type DbSet. This property acts as a collection that allows you to query the data in you table in database as though it were an in-memory collection of objects.

So, if you create an object of class **EquipmentDbContext** in controller named lets say **db**, then you can access the data in table with something like

```
db.Equipments
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand further on Cybercop's answer you would do something like this

```
using (var context = new EquipmentDBContext())
{
    var equipments = context.Equipments.ToList();
    var equipment = context.Equipments.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == 1);
    var blueThings= context.Equipments.Where(c=>c.Color == "blue").ToList();
}
```