# EF6 code first - How Get return Value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

In my code snippet below I am trying to get the value reurned by my stored procedure called ImportContacts but am lost as to how to get that value into variable procResult. Can anyone please help.

```
using (var context = new myDB())
{
     SqlParameter InstanceID = new SqlParameter("@InstanceID", IID);
     int procResult = (int)await context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("ImportContacts  @InstanceID", InstanceID);
     if (procResult ==-1)
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedures with EntityFramework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework)

Comment: Can you tell what is issue you are facing. Your code seems to be wrong the way you used await.

Comment: Vijay - I am new with EF6 so please help if you can. I know my code is wrong because its not working. What I want is during execution of my stored procedure I should get a value say 1 to indicate that something went wrong or 0 if all goes well. The procedure is basically an insert procedure

Comment: Add another parameter with Direction ReturnValue.

Comment: You have to use `SqlQuery<T>` instead.