# Error trying to execute update stored procedure using entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to run the following command in an ASP.Net Core app.

```
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
           "EXEC AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending @PracticeId @UserId @AdmissionId", 
           parameters: new[] { AdmissionId, assignments.UserId, assignments.PracticeId });
```

I've tried the actual command with these combinations as well

```
EXEC AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending @PracticeId, @UserId, @AdmissionId
AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending, @PracticeId, @UserId, @AdmissionId
```

The three values that are passed are three integers.  In case it matters here is the stored proc

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending]
    @AdmissionId INT,
    @UserId INT,
    @PracticeId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE
        AdmissionConsults 
    SET
        CurrentConsult = 0
    WHERE
        AdmissionId = @AdmissionId AND
        PracticeId = @PracticeId AND
        CurrentConsult = 1
END
```

When I run this though I get the following error: `No mapping to a relational type can be found for the CLR type 'Int32[]'.`

I'm not sure if this error is referring to the int values I am passing as parameters or perhaps since it's an update query it's trying to return an int value for the number of rows affected.  Either way I've yet to get it working.

Comment: Do you need commas to separate Params?

Comment: I had them originally and took them out to try and mimic how you would run it in SQL.

Comment: I'll try a couple combinations of that.

Comment: Are you sure `AdmissionId, assignments.UserId, assignments.PracticeId` are all `int`? From the error it looks like one of them is and integer array `int[]`

Comment: Yeah, I checked all the values that were being passed in.

Comment: Look at this posting and try passing in your parameters like they do in the answer with 8 upvotes - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework

Comment: I think you are passing the parameters incorrectly. Double check the syntax for passing multiple parameters in asp.net core

Comment: You're creating int array with the three parameter values and passing that as a single parameter, instead of passing individual int parameters.  That's the cause of the error message.

Comment: @STLDeveloper That's sounds correct.  Can you give me an example of how I need to change it?  I'm working through a few options now, but if you can post an example I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a method that should meet your requirements:

```
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>
                 {
                     new SqlParameter("@PracticeId", assignmentsPracticeId),
                     new SqlParameter("@UserId", assignmentsUserId),
                     new SqlParameter("@AdmissionId", AdmissionId)
                 };
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
       "EXEC AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending @PracticeId, @UserId, @AdmissionId", 
       parameters.ToArray());
```

Comment: One small change needed to your answer, you have to put a comma between the passed parameters in your command.

Comment: Of course.  Copy and paste error (mine, not yours).  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I found that the issue was I was passing in the values directly, and I needed to be passing a parameter, and not the int itself.  So what worked was this:

```
SqlParameter u = new SqlParameter("@UserId", assignments.UserId);
SqlParameter a = new SqlParameter("@AdmissionId", AdmissionId);
SqlParameter pr = new SqlParameter("@PracticeId", assignments.PracticeId);
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("EXEC AdmissionConsultEndCurrentAndPending @PracticeId, @UserId, @AdmissionId",
                                    parameters: new[] { a, u, pr });
```