# Use stored procedure in C# and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ef-database-first

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses an EF model (database-first approach). I have stored procedures defined in SQL Server that I need to use in my application. I've never done this before, any guidance regarding this will be appreciated. I did add the stored procedure and create the function for it but have no idea on how to add it to my controllers and views. For the code provided below, I simply want to add a card.

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[CreateLoyaltyCards]
    @NumberOfCards AS integer, 
    @CustomerID  AS integer 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NumberOfRows as integer = 0;
    DECLARE @LoopNumber as integer = 0

    WHILE @LoopNumber < @NumberOfCards
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Cards (CustomerID, CardDate)
        VALUES (@CustomerID, GetDate())

        SET @LoopNumber = @LoopNumber + 1
    END

    SELECT        
        Customers.CustomerCompanyName, Cards.CardNumber
    FROM            
        Customers 
    INNER JOIN
        Cards ON Customers.CustomerID = Cards.CustomerID
    WHERE 
        Customers.CustomerID = @CustomerID
    ORDER BY 
       CardID ASC
       OFFSET @NumberOfRows ROWS
       FETCH NEXT @NumberOfCards ROWS ONLY
END
```

CardsController // this is where I need to use the stored procedure

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName");
    return View();
}

// POST: Cards/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CardID,CardNumber,CustomerID,StoreCustomerID,CardDate,CardStatus,CardNumber2,DiscountLevelID,LoyaltyLevelID,GiftCardEnabled,LoyaltyEnabled")] Card card)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Cards.Add(card);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "CustomerCompanyName", card.CustomerID);
    return View(card);
}
```

This is the stored procedure in context class

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Card> CreateCards(Nullable<int> numberOfCards, Nullable<int> customerID)
{
    var numberOfCardsParameter = numberOfCards.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("NumberOfCards", numberOfCards) :
            new ObjectParameter("NumberOfCards", typeof(int));

    var customerIDParameter = customerID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", customerID) :
            new ObjectParameter("CustomerID", typeof(int));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Card>("CreateCards", numberOfCardsParameter, customerIDParameter);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Stored Procedures with EntityFramework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264750/how-to-call-stored-procedures-with-entityframework)

Comment: You can not call the stored procedure method using db?

Comment: It calls the stored procedure using db but what goes in the parameter?

Comment: The method has parameters. You just need to call the method with the parameters values. Link shared by krillgar didn't help?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create object of EF class and call directly the function(created from SP).

e.g. suppose **context** is your object.

```
    context.CreateCards(numberOfCards, customerID);
```